# React - this.props.appRecommendData.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, web-applications, async-await

I am a beginner at ReactJS, I aim to make an app searching web application. Here is my idea:
In `app.js`, I have a state: `appRecommendData` which retrieve the result from the app store API and do searching by a function `filterAppRecommend()`, and then rendered by a component called `AppRecommend`, I found that I cannot render the result initially, but it works after typing, because of the async problem(when I still fetching the data, the export function have started), then I tried to add `async` and `await` to solve it, it works but the `props.map` is not function, can anyone help to solve it/suggest other way to fix it? below is my code:

`app.js`:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filteredAppList: [],
      filteredRecommend:filterAppRecommend("",10)
    };
  }
  handleSearchChange = event =>{
    this.setState({
                  filteredRecommend:filterAppRecommend(event.target.value,10)
                });
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
        <div className="search-bar"><SearchInput textChange={this.handleSearchChange} /></div>     
          <div className="App-recommendation">
            <AppRecommend appRecommendData={this.state.filteredRecommend}/>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
}
```

In`filterAppRecommend.js`:

```
export default async function filterAppRecommend(searchText, maxResults) {
    console.log("maxResults is"+maxResults);
    const api = await fetch("https://itunes.apple.com/hk/rss/topgrossingapplications/limit=10/json")
  .then(results=>results.json());
      console.log(api);
      let datas = api.feed.entry;
      console.log(datas);
    return datas.filter(data => {
        if(searchText===""){
          return true;
      }
      if (data["im:name"].label.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
      }
      if (data["im:name"].label.includes(searchText)) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    })
    .slice(0, maxResults);

}
```

In Component `AppRecommend`:

```
class AppRecommmend extends PureComponent{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading:false,
        };
    }
    render(){
        console.log(this.props.appRecommendData.type); //will show undefined
        return(
        <div className="component-AppRecommend">
        {this.props.appRecommendData.map(appRecommendData=>(
            <AppRecommmendCol
            imgSource={appRecommendData["im:image"][1].label}
            title={appRecommendData["im:name"].label}/>
        ))}
        </div>
    );}
}
AppRecommmend.propTypes = {
  appRecommendData: PropTypes.oneOfType([
      PropTypes.object,
      PropTypes.array
  ])
}
export default AppRecommmend
```

Comment: Please try and format your code, as it's quite hard to read. `filterAppRecommend` is asynchronous, so you can't use `x` directly the way you do in the constructor of `App`.

Comment: Formatted some of them, see if it is better. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you use .map to go through collection of data, appRecommendData should be an array. filterAppRecommend should return data as array. You can use sth like this to get initial value:

```
//App.js

async componentDidMount() {
   const filteredRecommend = await filterAppRecommend("",10);
   this.setState({ filteredRecommend });
}
```

In AppRecommmend.js use

```
AppRecommmend.defaultProps = {
appRecommendData : []
}
```

Comment: It can shows all the results initially but the Type error happens again when I type in the search input.

Comment: So in handleSearchChange() you can use async\await `const filteredRecommend  = await filterAppRecommend(e.target.value)`  and then setState(), like in CDM.

Comment: When filtering I suggest to use debounce function from lodash library to delay ajax call, because on every key press you will produce new ajax call.

Comment: e is an event in your case